# I need a simple image editing software

Tags: windows-7

It should

1. Allow going to the next pics with a click of a button
2. Allow simple crop editing

That's it.

No need photoshop. I need something that my employee can use fast.

Comment: Paint.NET is quick, feature rich, and simple to use.  I would just use the built-in tool for real simple modifications.

Comment: I modify pixels by hand using a hex editor :)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Paint and the Microsoft Image Viewer built into Windows 7 will allow you to do both of these things.

Answer (score 2):

Paint.net is cool and free, take it: http://www.getpaint.net/download.html

[EDITED]
Now after I read your question again - IrfanView can do it as well (is not an editing software though): http://www.irfanview.net